# How to stop Jupyter from printing out modified plotting parameters?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the screenshot below, you see that when I do `plt.xticks(range(0, 300, 10))`, it prints out the xticks objects (indicated in screenshot). How can I stop Jupyter from printing them out?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the call of `plt.xticks`. Usually, the underscore is used when you assign something that you won't use. For instance:

```
_ = plt.xticks(range(0, 300, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `plt.show()` at the end of your code.